# How to mirror C directory structure using Doxygen groups?

Tags: c, doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

I need some basic help using Doxygen on C code. All basic docs are coming out fine, and I want help structuring the big long long list of files and functions.

I have a C source tree which looks like this:

```
src/
 +--util/
    +--file1.h
    +--file1.c
    +--file2.h
    +--file2.c
 +--stats/
    +--file3.h
 +--etc/
```

Very standard. Currently doxygen generates a flat file list of all files. We refer to each dub-dir of src/ as a 'module', and so documenting this seems like a nice fit for Doxygen modules/groups.

How exactly should I use the grouping commands to mirror the directory structure above? I want to have a module util in the generated docs which links to the file1 and file2 docs. Exactly like JavaDoc would treat a package.

Adding the /addtogroup util & @{ tags to each header file generated a mini-site with a flattened list of all data-structures etc within all the headers, which isn't what I expected or wanted. Perhaps this is what doxygen groups are supposed to do though, ie, document an API uniformly when the code is implemented across multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler option to using modules is to use `@page` and `@subpage`. To get something similar to your described layout you could use the following:

```
@page util Util
This page describes util module.
@subpage file1
@subpage file2

@page stats Stats
This page describes stats module.
@subpage file3

@page etc
Blah blah blah

@page file1 File 1
This is file 1.

@page file2 File 2
This is file 2.

@page file3 File 3
This is file 3.
```

These comments can of course be contained in one file or many. Typically I'd put the `@page file1` in file1.h, `@page file2` in file2.h, etc, and the `@subpage` comments in a more top-level header or main source file.